# Windows IIS Authentication not working with FQDN but is without it

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, authentication

I have an Intranet website, not internet, and whenever I go to

```
http://mysite
```

The website accepts my integrated authentication of the logged in user on the computer/client via IE.

if I go to the FQDN

```
http://mysite.something.com
```

I get prompted for my username and password.

They're the same and site and web pages.  What can I do to make them both accept my credentials from IE/logged in user?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to [this question][1] over on Stackoverflow.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1030177/66169

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the FQDN in IE's "Intranet" security zone?  If not you will need to add it in, or add in the *.mydomain.com wildcard.

The "Intranet" zone is inferred if you use just the server name (i.e. there are no dots in your URL), but often the "Internet" zone is used if you use the FQDN.

Windows Integrated Authentication is not automatically used for sites in the "Internet" zone.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650

Comment: Well, that is not cool. But I guess we can live with it for now.  Thanks anyhow!

Comment: well, this sucks.  But thanks for the info anyhow!